# Map of Objects that all inherit from the same class, calling object method rather than the parent; c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have a `Component` class, which is the parent class, and for example a `Sprite` class. `Sprite` also has various children for animation, but that is not the focus of this question. I also have a component manager which holds a `map<string, Component>`. I store every component I create in this map. Currently there are 12 types of components, but that will increase.

My `Component` class has `virtual void draw()` and `update()` functions, and the same for `Sprite` in this case. When I loop through the map of components, however, it only calls the `Component` `draw()` and `update()`.

I haven’t really been able to find an answer that has actually worked for me yet.

Comment: Are you storing pointers in the map or objects? You really should be storing pointers otherwise you will run into the 'object slicing' problem, which has exactly the symptoms you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re experiencing [*object slicing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)—since your `map` only stores `Component` objects *by value*, those objects do not include any of the information provided by `Component` subclasses. Generally speaking, subtype polymorphism only works through pointer types, not value types. So you need to store the instances by pointer, preferably `std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Component>>`:

```
components["example"] = std::unique_ptr<Component>(new Example());
```

If you are using a non-C++11 compiler, use `std::map<std::string, Component*>`:

```
components["example"] = new Example();
```

And make sure you `delete` the `Component` objects during cleanup, e.g., in the destructor of your component manager. C++03:

```
for (std::map<std::string, Component*>::const_iterator i = components.begin();
    i != components.end(); ++i)
    delete i->second;
```

C++11:

```
for (const auto& i : components)
    delete i.second;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and explaining with examples.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is quite common, it's called *slicing*. The map doesn't contain the original objects, it contains *copies* of the objects. The copy isn't the type that you tried to insert into the map, it's the base type that you declared for the map.

The only way around this is to store pointers rather than the objects themselves. Typically this is using a smart pointer such as `shared_ptr` so that cleanup is automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like slicing to me, try storing pointers to your components in the map.